Kafka python 2.0.2. version , getting Socket disconnected error /Kafka timeout error
When our lambda send messages to Kafka we are seeing multiple error messages.
Error1 - "Node 1 connection failed -- refreshing metadata"
Error2 - Got error produce response on topic-partition TopicPartition(topic="topic1"...
When error 2 happens, if retried and published message before time out, then error 4 happens or else error 3.
Error 3- Kafkatimeouterror.  (message lost)
Error 4 - Error: KafkaConnectionError: socket disconnected.(message consumed late)
Modified all the configs.
This is the kafka config
{'compression_type': 'snappy', 'acks': 'all', 'batch_size':16000, 'linger_ms': 5, 'max_in_flight_requests_per_connection': 5, 'request_timeout_ms':300000, 'retries':sys.maxsize,'buffer_memory': 134217728}
